# Without writing FPI(Formal Public Identifier) hibernate.cfg.xml still works. Why?

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, xhtml, dtd

> In Hibernate, we write hibernate configuration file as

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

> in such case if we remove FPI(Formal Public Identifier) then still it is working. Why? Then what is the need to writing FPI ?
>
> Ex:- If we write hibernate configuration file as

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    ""
    "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

Comment: The FPI (and also the system identifier) are used to locate the DTD (declarations of elements and attributes). However, XML generally doesn't require such declarations; hibernate has the elements and attributes it uses hardcoded in its application. The DTD would be useful if you want to validate the hibernate config file independently of the hibernate libs. SGML (of which XML is a subset) OTOH, could require a DTD for even parsing a document; for example, HTML has "auto-closing" elements the parser needs to know about.

Answer (score 0):

Doctype / XML Schema can be used to check whether an XML file is well formed. Hibernate doesn't need to care about it, as long as the contents *are* well formed (which it will certainly notice while parsing the XML contents).

Having it in the file will allow tools to provide you with additional functionality such as auto-complete and validity checking. It's not an absolute requirement.